# How to make a SearchView inside MaterialToolbar using menu item

Tags: android, kotlin

Good day sirs/maams.
I am asking for your help.
I want to implement a SearchView out of a menu item inside my MaterialToolbar.

Here's my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
                android:theme="@style/CustomSearchView"
                app:title="Dashboard"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_24"
                app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
                style="@style/MaterialToolbar"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:title="Search"
        android:id="@+id/top_nav_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.top_app_bar, menu)

        val searchItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.top_nav_search)


        if(searchItem != null){
            val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {

                    //show submitted text for testing purposes.
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Looking for $query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    return true
                }

                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                    return true
                }

            })
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

The result is whenever I try to submit a text, the toast message does not appear. It seems that my code doesn't work.
Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The result is whenever I try to submit a text, the toast message does not appear. It seems that my code doesn't work.

Your code looks okay, but you are adding a menu using `onCreateOptionsMenu` so no need to define it again in `activity_mian.xml`. You are setting the listener to different SearchView that you see on the screen. That is the reason that toast is not displaying on submit. Simply remove the ToolBar from your `activity_main` keep a simple `LinearLayout`, then it should work.

Make sure you are adding ActionBar Theme in styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
 </style>
```

And add it in the Manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

OR

Simply, why can't we add the search view directly in `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />

    <!--Remaining activity UI goes here-->


</LinearLayout>
```

custom_toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:translationZ="6dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:queryHint="Search" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then use it in your `MainActivity` under `onCreate()`

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_toolbar.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                if (!query.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Looking for $query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jay Garzon is it worked?

Comment: This worked like charm! No need to call "onCreateOptionsMenu".
What I did is a created a searchview inside my toolbar and in the MainActivity.kt, I call that searchview and perform my desired tasks. However, I have to remove the relative layout inside the toolbar since it occupy all the remaining space inside my toolbar hence, my app:title does not show because it overlapped with the relative layout. I set the layout_gravity of my searchview equals to end. Thank you man!
Sorry for late response hope you have a wonderful day mate.

Comment: Happy that it's worked for you, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed like this
Globle variable

```
 private lateinit var searchView: SearchView
```

You can do the same

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_filter_menu, menu)
        searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.search).actionView as SearchView
        searchView.queryHint = getString(R.string.search_student_txt)
        searchView.maxWidth = Int.MAX_VALUE
        searchView.findViewById<View>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_plate)
            .setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(s: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(s: String?): Boolean {
                searchText(s)
                return true
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```